# chrome extensions - how to get chrome-store URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to get the chrome-store URL of a chrome extension inside the extension?

I would like to provide the URL of the "support" page for the users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`chrome.runtime.id`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-id) is the id of your extension, so you want
`"https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/"+chrome.runtime.id`